# sql get max date before starting date while joining two dates

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have two tables. Table A has an id and a starting date. Table B has rows with an id and a date. Each id in table B may correspond to multiple dates. How can I join table B onto A such that I get the largest date in table B for that id that occurs prior to the starting date?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1):

> I get the largest date in table B for that id that occurs prior to the starting date?

I would suggest a correlated subquery:

```
select a.*,
       (select max(b.date)
        from b
        where b.id = a.id and b.date < a.starting_date
       ) as max_preceding_b_date
from a;
```

For performance, you want an index on `b(id, date)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use subquery with group by for that.

```
select id, max(date) MaxDate from tableB b
where date<(select starting_date from tableA a where a.id=b.id)
group by id
```

DB-Fiddle:

```
 create table tableA (id int , starting_date date);
 insert into tableA values (1,'2021-01-01');
 insert into tableA values (2,'2021-01-05');

 create table tableB (id int , dates date);
 insert into tableB values(1,'2021-01-01');
 insert into tableB values(1,'2020-01-01');
 insert into tableB values(1,'2020-12-25');
 insert into tableB values(2,'2021-01-05');
```

Query:

```
 select id, max(dates) MaxDate from tableB b
 where dates<(select starting_date from tableA a where a.id=b.id)
 group by id
```

Output:

| id | MaxDate |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-12-25 |

*db<fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=10637fdb68101b51ac42339d7b976141)*